# Putting generated data in a matrix format

Tags: r, simulation, matrix

I have one question about putting a simulated data in a matrix format, but I cannot suitably write its program in R, and constantly receive an error, I guess my "rep" definition and final "Matrix" expression are somehow wrong, but I do not know how to fix them. Here my specific question is:

I would like to produce a matrix contains generated values. I have 20000 generated values for x and y. As the output, I like to have a (2000 by 10) matrix that each column of the matrix contains the output of following for loop.

My R.code:

```
x=rnorm(2e4,5,6)
vofdiv=quantile(x,probs=seq(0,1,0.1))
y=rnorm(2e4,4,6)
Matrix=rep(NULL,2000)
for(i in 1:10)
{
Matrix[i]=y[(x>=vofdiv[i] & x<vofdiv[i+1])]  #The i(th) col of matrix
}
Matrix   # A 2000*10 Matrix, as the final output
```

I highly appreciate that someone helps me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems here.

First of all, the correct way to define an empty matrix of size `2e4*10`, would be

```
Matrix <- matrix(NA, 2e4, 10)
```

Although you could potentially create a matrix using your way(`rep`) and then use `dim`, something like

```
Matrix <- rep(NA, 2e5)
dim(Matrix) <- c(2e4, 10)
```

Second problem is, when trying to insert into a column in a `matrix`, you need to index it correctly, i.e.,

```
Matrix[, i] <-
```

instead of

```
Matrix[i] <-
```

The latter will index `Matrix` as if it was a vector (which is it basically is). In other words, it will convert a 2000*10 `matrix` to a 20000 length single `vector` and index it.

The third problem is, that when your loop reaches `i = 11` and you are running `x<vofdiv[i+1]` you are always excluding the last values which are  `x == vofdiv[11]`, thus you are always getting less than 2000 values:

```
for(i in 1:10)
{
  print(length(y[ (x >= vofdiv[i] & x < vofdiv[i+1])]))
}
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 2000
# [1] 1999 <----
```

Thus, it will give you an error if you will try to replace 2000 length vector with 1999 length one, because a `matrix` in R can't contain different dimensions for each column.

The workaround would be to add `=` to your last statement, such as

```
Matrix <- matrix(NA, 2e4, 10)
for(i in 1:10)
  {
    Matrix[, i] <- y[x >= vofdiv[i] & x <= vofdiv[i + 1]] 
  }
```